# How to get smaller latex brackets in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I have the following expression in matplotlib, using latex code:

```
ax.set_xlabel(r'\langle \epsilon \rangle', fontsize=18)
```

While rendering the epsilon is significantly smaller than the brackets. The brackets are sized to "wrap" an uppercase letter. How do I make the brackets smaller?

Comment: is `usetex` true or false? I also suspect that a) it will be tricky to do and b) the current behaviour is 'correct'.

Answer (score 2):

In LaTeX's math-mode one can make things smaller using:

- `\scriptstyle` or
- `\scriptscriptstyle`

However these expressions don't work in default matplotlib backend:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import matplotlib
custom_preamble = {
    "text.usetex": True,
    }

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


x = range(5)
y = range(5)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.text(0.5, 0.5,
    r"${\scriptscriptstyle(} {\scriptstyle(} (\varepsilon$",
    horizontalalignment = 'center',
    backgroundcolor = "white",
    verticalalignment = 'center',
    transform = ax.transAxes,
    )

ax.plot(x, y)

fig.savefig("mwe-1.png")
```

Results in:

[image]

However for a better LaTeX support one can use pgf backend, and then it works:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("pgf")
# the rest is the same as in the code above
```

Result:

[image]

`pgf` backend was added to matplotlib 1.3. I think You'll need a working XeTeX installed on Your system (I think the relative binary is called `xelatex`). Both major LaTeX distributions (MiKTeX and TeXLive) allow to install XeTeX.

Comment: +1 because it works, but seems to break some other parts of the code. Thank you!

Comment: @astabada: it should not really break no other parts of the code. If in trouble edit Your question and post MWE.